# Common elements from two Perl arrays

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing Two Arrays Using Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933347/comparing-two-arrays-using-perl)

I am trying to find elements that are common in both the files: 
below is my code. Please tell me what mistake I am doing.

```
open IN,  "New_CLDB.txt"     or die "couldn't locate input file";
open IN1, "New_adherent.txt" or die "couldn't locate input file";
use Data::Dumper;
@array = ();
while (<IN>) {
    $line = $_;
    chomp $line;
    $a[$i] = $line;
    ++$i;
}
while (<IN1>) {
    $line1 = $_;
    chomp $line1;
    $b[$m] = $line1;
    ++$m;
}
for ( $k = 0; $k < $i; ++$k ) {
    for ( $f = 0; $f < $m; ++$f ) {
        if ( $a[$k] ne $b[$f] ) {
            push( @array, $a[$k] );
        }
    }
}
print @array, "\n";
```

Comment: @zidgon: its printing infinite values. FYI-Both the files have one list

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933347/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421463/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714667/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591747/ ,

Comment: [How do I compute the difference of two arrays? How do I compute the intersection of two arrays?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays%3f--How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays%3f)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537838/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421232/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064781/

Comment: Your are testing for string inequality (`ne`) when you want equality (`eq`), change that and break the inner loop after `push` using `last`, and your code will only print common elements. For a more Perlish solution look at ikegami´s answer.

Comment: The #1 thing is that you're not using hashes.  When you're thinking of creating a bunch of things that you're going to look up repeatedly, you use a hash.  Look at the Perl FAQ entries that brian d foy linked to above.

Comment: "Please tell me what mistake I am doing." You're not checking the Perl FAQ first :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things one should improve:

1. Always `use strict;` and `use warnings;`
2. Use the three argument version of `open`
3. Use lexical filehandles
4. Use *meaningful* formatting/indention
5. Append an array with `push @array, $value;`

And for SO questions ... what exactly is your problem and what do you expect.

Comment: Maybe because the OP could fix all of these things and still not be any closer to an answer to her question.

Answer (score 6):

> Please tell me what mistake I am doing.

From superficially eyeballing your code, here's a list:

- not using the `strict` pragma
- not having a precise spec of what you want to achieve
- attempting to do too much at once

Take a step away from the code and think about it in plain English. What would you need to do?

- read files - open, read, close
- read file data into an array - how exactly?
- use a function not to repeat yourself for file A and file B
- compare arrays

Do each task in isolation, always using `strict`. Always. Only then compose the single steps to a larger script.

You could also take a look at [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933347/comparing-two-arrays-using-perl).

Answer (score 3):

If there are no duplicates in the second set:

```
my %set1;
while (<$fh1>) {
   chomp;
   ++$set1{$_};
}

while (<$fh2>) {
   chomp;
   print("$_ is common to both sets\n")
      if $set1{$_};
}
```

If there are possibly duplicates in the second set:

```
my %set1;
while (<$fh1>) {
   chomp;
   ++$set1{$_};
}

my %set2;
while (<$fh2>) {
   chomp;
   print("$_ is common to both sets\n")
      if $set1{$_} && !$set2{$_}++;
}
```